# How do I determine whether a buffer is on the GPU or the CPU?

Tags: c, memory, cuda, gpu, nvidia

In C/CUDA, if I am passed a pointer, how can I programmatically determine whether the pointer points to memory on the CPU or the GPU? Is there a CUDA function for this purpose?

Comment: why would you need this information?

Comment: "if I am passed a pointer" you mean if you passed the pointer to the GPU?

Comment: @scatman I think he means he's trying to take the results of `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMallocHost` and pass them into the same function, then work out which is which afterwards. I think you'd do better just keeping them separate to start with.

Comment: Some data might be generated on the CPU or the GPU, then passed to a function I'm writing. I could have two functions, one for each case, but I'd rather just have one function which copies the data to the GPU if it isn't there already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how it is with CUDA 4.0, but in 3.2 you simply cannot deduct if it is CPU or GPU pointer based solely on the address stored in it.

A way around it would be to create a class `CudaPtr<T>`, hide a pointer there and provide basic functionality (e.g. `memset`, `memload`, `memstore`, `memalloc` etc. which would in turn use CUDA stuff).

Then, if you have a function which may operate on host or on device, you can easily overload it for `T*` and `CudaPtr<T>`.

---

Update: Since the Unified Memory Addressing and new CUDA toolkit things have changed a bit. It seems you can now make such distinction at run time via [cuPointerGetAttribute](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__UNIFIED.html)

Comment: Is there a reason why one can't deduce the location of the memory? For example, can the device/GPU memory address space overlap (i.e. have the same addresses as) the host/CPU memory address space, even in theory? Or is it simply that such a  function is not currently available?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the values in an application? I'd guess that device pointers are in their own memory space, probably 0-based so you'd have 0-256MB say, whereas if your app loads into Windows memory at 0x400000 as is traditional then you'll also have pointers in that range for your code. But they'd refer to completely different memory. Or, maybe all device pointers have their top two bits set or something so they can be distinguished? I don't have CUDA hardware here to try right now.

Comment: Yes, the pointer values tend to be very different for GPU and CPU buffers, but I'm after a solution that is robust to other systems and platforms, not ad hoc. A CUDA function would have been good but it seems there isn't one.